# cURL secure FTP access (--ftp-ssl-control works but --ftp-ssl doesn't)

Tags: curl, ssl, ftp

The title of this question hopefully explains the problem, but I'm trying to connect to a remote FTP server using cURL in a shell script I'm currently writing.

On my local machine I'm running this command:

```
curl --verbose --ftp-ssl -3 --user 'USER:PASS' --disable-epsv ftp://ftp.domain.com:21
```

and after the data connection has been established I see this output:

```
< 230 User USER logged in
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ 0 successful
> PROT P
< 200 Protection set to Private
> PWD
< 257 "/" is the current directory
* Entry path is '/'
> PASV
* Connect data stream passively
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (000,000,000,000,206,106).
*   Trying 000.000.000.000... connected
* Connecting to 000.000.000.000 (000.000.000.000) port 52842
> TYPE A
< 200 Type set to A
> LIST
< 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
* Doing the SSL/TLS handshake on the data stream
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
* Maxdownload = -1
drwxr-xr-x   2 myserver 29894        4096 May 11 17:52 .
drwxr-xr-x   2 myserver 29894        4096 May 11 17:52 ..
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Remembering we are in dir ""
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
< 226 Transfer complete
* Connection #0 to host ftp.domain.com left intact
> QUIT
< 221 Goodbye.
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Running the same command on the server gives me this instead:

```
< 230 User USER logged in
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ 0 successful
> PROT P
< 200 Protection set to Private
> PWD
< 257 "/" is the current directory
* Entry path is '/'
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||49727|)
*   Trying 2a01:3b0:1:a0::1:2... connected
* Connecting to 2a01:3b0:1:a0::1:2 (2a01:3b0:1:a0::1:2) port 49727
> TYPE A
< 200 Type set to A
> LIST
< 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
* Doing the SSL/TLS handshake on the data stream
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
* Maxdownload = -1
* Remembering we are in dir ""
< 425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
* server did not report OK, got 425
* Connection #0 to host ftp.domain.com left intact
curl: (18) server did not report OK, got 425
> QUIT
< 221 Goodbye.
* Closing connection #0
```

If I use the --ftp-ssl-control switch it works on the server, but I want to encrypt the data transfer as well as the authentication.

Does anyone know what the way to resolve this is please? I can't work out if this is a problem with the firewall on the server or to do with the SSL connection and/or the session management - I've tried using the --no-sessionid and --sessionid options but it didn't make any difference, and I get the same results whether I'm using an active or passive connection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add more debug information so that one can see what the reply to the `PROT P` command is which specifies the protection level of the data connection?

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my question now. The difference between the two outputs seems to be that the local machine is using PASV rather than EPSV and is also reusing the SSL session. Please note that I've omitted the SSL certificate details after the "* Server certificate:" line and screened the IP address.

Comment: If you are using the exact same command on the server, e.g. with `--disable-epsv` it should not use EPSV - but it obviously does. Could it be, that it is also ignoring the option to reuse the SSL session? proftpd and probably others require in the default setup that the session gets reused between control and data SSL connection, so this might explain the `425...not permitted`.

Comment: It looks like you have a different version of curl on the server - the cipher is reported in a different format.

Comment: Thanks Steffen - it does seem to be ignoring the --sessionid setting. The version of cURL is the same on both systems (7.19.7) but the platforms are different (local machine is OS X, server is CentOS) and one of the libraries is different (local machine is OpenSSL/0.9.8y, server is NSS/3.14.0.0). I had read that there was an issue with proftpd but I can't tell from the log what type of FTP server is being used.